# EclEmma, Java8 and Lambda - no coverage on lambda expression

Tags: java-8, jacoco, eclemma

I have a Java project under Eclipse Luna, with EclEmma  2.3.1.201405111647 (latest), which use Jacoco 0.7.1, which have support for Java 8 as stated in their [changelog](http://www.eclemma.org/changes.html):

> "Version 2.3.1 (2014/05/11)
>
> ```
> Fixed ASM 5.0.1 dependency conflicts with new ASM bundles in Eclipse 4.4 (GitHub #83).
> Upgrade to JaCoCo 0.7.1 for full Java 8 support.
> ```

I now have the following toString:

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // [BLOCK0]
    if (0 == value) {
      return "0B";
    }
    // [BLOCK1]
    final MutableLong val = new MutableLong(value);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // [BLOCK2]
    Arrays.asList(TERA_BYTES, GIGA_BYTES, MEGA_BYTES, KILO_BYTES, BYTES).forEach(unit -> {
      // [BLOCK3]
      long divider = unit.toBytes(1);
      long n = val.longValue() / divider;
      if (0 != n) {
        sb.append(n).append(unit.getUnitCharacter());
        val.subtract(n * divider);
      }
    });
    // [BLOCK4]
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

I won't put the Junit test, because I know it goes 100% coverage. I can prove it by moving the lamdba expression into a `appendToString` method, and remplace the `forEach` with a *for-each* `for (V value : Iterable<V>)`.

The result is, when I do "Coverage as Junit Test", the following:

- BLOCK0 is all green
- BLOCK1 is all green
- BLOCK2 is green, up to the `forEach(unit -> {`
- BLOCK3 is white (as if it were ignored lines)
- BLOCK4 is all green.

Can someone explain me why Jacoco can't detect coverage in lambda ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lambda expression bodies are compiled into synthetic methods, but [as far as I read](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/filtering-JAVAC.SYNTHMETH), synthetic methods are unconditionally filtered out in the code coverage analysis.

By looking at the [Change History](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html) of JaCoCo I see

> ### Snapshot Build 0.7.2.201408210455 (2014/08/21)
>
> **Fixed Bugs**
>
> Do not ignore synthetic lambda methods to get code coverage for Java 8 lambda expressions (GitHub #232).

which seems to address your issue. Since you are using EclEmma `2.3.1` which is using JaCoCo version `0.7.1` you just need an update.

Comment: It appears that the eclEmma eclipse updatesite / marketplace is not yet updated to this version, so you will have to do a manual download and install