# How do Iget information about branches in Java using ASM?

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I want to collect some information about branches in ASM such as:

- Start line
- End line
- Branch type (part of "if", a boolean expression in a larger expressions an and/or, while, return, etc).

I'll appreciate any hints on ow to access the problem what's the best approach to write reliable tests.

Thanks.

Comment: Java byte code doesn’t work that way. Lines are only available as optional debugging information and do not necessarily be complete enough for that. Further, there is no way to recognize whether a branch is part of an `if` statement, the short circuiting `&&` or `||`, or a ternary conditional expression. In some cases, you might not even be able to distinguish them from loops.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer!
Second, do you know how code coverage tools handles it?
1) Able to mark an entire branch as not accessed?
2) Able to mark that a specific boolean expression inside an if hasn't been called during unit tests?

Comment: Well, unless the tool has its own compiler, it has to rely on the presence of the debugging attributes. Then, if you have the source code, you can associate byte code with statements without needing to understand the source, as you can show the user the associated line and the user sees and understands the statement in that line. Of course, this has limitations. If you write an entire (probably nested) `if` statement in a single line, tools relying on the standard `LineNumberTable` are lost. But note that certain artifacts, like method invocations and field accesses *are* recognizable.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25627582/2711488) is an example of a code coverage tool settling on the general structure of a class file and the `LineNumberTable`, failing to understand the actual (source) code structure.

Comment: @Holger - thanks!
Regarding the CC tool - you are refering to JaCoCo?

Comment: I guess, other tools are similar. If a tool has its own compiler, its documentation would tell you…

Comment: @Holger - regrading the artifacts which are accessible, basically you are saying that if I have a compositie if such as "if (getAge()>18 || getGender()=="male")", I'll able to use the the names of the getters in order to understand which branch has been hit?

Comment: Exactly. If there are member with distinct names accessed, you’ll recognize them in source code, even if you don’t have a full-fledged parser. Netbeans’ debugger has a similar feature, allowing to decide whether to enter a method invocation, even if there are multiple in one line.