# Fortify doesn't recognize lambda

Tags: java, java-8, fortify

> Dead Code: Unused Method

Fortify is detecting lambda methods as unused. For instance: I have the below method: `getCountryCode`, even though its used in many places, fortify is reporting it as an unused method.

```
private List<String> getCountryCodeAsList(Map<Long, String> countryData, List<String> nationalityRestriction) {
    return nationalityRestriction.parallelStream().filter(r -> !org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank(r))
            .map(r -> getCountryCode(countryData, r)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private String getCountryCode(Map<Long, String> countryData, String r) {
    return !org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank(r) ? countryData.get(Long.parseLong(r)): null;
}
```

How to fix this issue? Any pointers?

Comment: Can I know why it is down voted. Give the reason before down vote, it helps the person to understand the issue with the question.

Comment: if you cannot give a reason, stop giving any votes, it doesnt make any sense at all...

Comment: Not sure though what fortify does, but to clarify the question, which method is unused -`getCountryCodeAsList` or `getCountryCode`?

Comment: getCountryCode is flagged as unused

Comment: may be fortify does not work with java-8? may be raise an issue to them? the way you showed this code, it is clearly used

Comment: @Eugene in that case, it could be an issue similar to [the one, JaCoCo had when Java 8 was new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25627582/2711488). But it might be worth noting that in the example of this question, there’s redundancy in the `isBlank(r)` test, which leads to a code path never taken (the returning `null` alternative in `getCountryCode`).

Answer (score 3):

Currently Fortify SCA only supports lambdas in a subset of the languages it can scan that use lambda expressions.  Fortify SCA implemented a new built-in analyzer that they call the Higher Order analyzer to accomplish this, but it will only work with the following languages: JavaScript, Python, Ruby, and Swift.

So the short answer to your question is that you can't really do anything until Fortify implements support for Java lambda expressions in their Higher Order analyzer.

[image: Section from the Fortify SCA 18.20 user guide documentation]